# Show Flash video in a layer popup

Tags: flash, adobe, dhtml

Would like to show a flash video in a layer popup (a layer rests above the current page, darkens the background and shows the video front and center) that is compatible with all major browsers (Opera, FF3.x, IE6,7 and 8)

Is there any code that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Shadowbox.js](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/); the demos look like what you're describing.

Disclaimers: I haven't tried it myself, and commercial use requires a fee.

Comment: very nice. there's a nice link to http://www.stickmanlabs.com/lightwindow that seems to be licensed under the MIT style license - really cool